# Razor highlight stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have modular MVC Portal-Plugin application. When I've changed output path of mvc application Razor highlight and intellisense stop to work in cshtml files. Can anybody faced with this issue before? I've also added post build event to copy Views into custom directory

I have main "Container" MVC application and modules (mvc projects)

Main mvc application and modules reside in one solution

There is next options on each module MVC application:

```
Output Path :   ..\Container\bin\

Post build Event:   xcopy "$(ProjectDir)\Views" "..\Modules\$(ProjectName)\Views" /s /i /y
```

After this manipulations my Razor intelisense and highlight stop to work in module application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve my problem. It was problem with output path.

I've just put default output path "bin\" and add post build event to copy my dll from this folder into another one.

Comment: Nice work! and thanks for adding the answer to your question, so programmers with same issue can get help here:)

Answer (score 3):

Solved it and blogged about it in here...

http://mhammadchehab.com/wordpress/2013/12/enabling-intellisense-for-razor-in-class-library-mvc-5-razor-3-0/

*Right Click – >Manage Nuget Packages

*Click on the installed Packages.

*Click Uninstall.

*When your done search for MVC 5 online and install the Library.

*Right click on your project and go to properties

*Select Build

*On Configuration select all configuration.

*Go to the output path and type “bin\”

*Clean your project and rebuild.

*Make sure that your cshtml file is closed.

*Reopen your view file and BOOOOOOM it works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Also, self-promotion is frowned upon here; visit the Help Center to learn under which conditions this is allowed.

Comment: The linked domain has expired. And the answer is so sparse not to mention which NuGet package to uninstall...

Comment: seriously, that is almost 3 years ago!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your web.config file in your `Visual studio project` contain the following lines:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="MyCustomHelpers" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>\
```

These lines give you the intelli sense.

Comment: Please, look on my changed question. You approach is not working, I've just tested it. :(

Comment: So, you're saying that the intelli sense only dissapears when changing to other output path?

Comment: Yes. I've just tested it. It dissapears only when I change output path.

Comment: It is back you when set output path the default?

Comment: Exactly. I've found some interesting link http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/305675. Please, take a look to second post

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Output Path to bin/ is the correct answere, but I extended it a bit. the steps needed for all creating a "vanilla" class library with intellisense support are the following

Create or open an existing class library project (if you open an existing one be sure to remove the MVC5 nuget package)

Add the MVC (5.0) nuget package (right click project in solution explorer -> Manage NuGet Packages -> search for MVC and install “Microsoft ASP.NET MVC”)

Close any and all open .cshtml files

Right click project -> Properties -> Build -> change Output path to “bin/”

Add the following minimal Web.config to the root of your class library project ( the web 
config file is solely needed for intellisense. Configuration (via Web.config) should be done in the WebApplication hosting your ClassLibrary assembly)

Clean and Build the solution.

Open cshtml file

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web> 

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <!-- add other namespaces for views here -->
        <!-- e.g. your own project's, Lib.Views.Etc -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

I also just blogged about this http://thetoeb.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/enabling-mvc5-intellisense-in-a-classlibrary-project/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it as follows. In web.Config, add this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

For reference, `webpages:Version` does this:

> If the key is missing from web.config file such as default Razor V2/V3
>   website, VS will use bin directory’s razor dll version to determine
>   the design time razor engine dll to load.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27918972/3146