# MVC View is not displaying the code correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have MVC project on VS 2012, when i open the view it's not displaying the code correctly, i mean everything [server side code] in black color.
Can anyone tell me why?

[image]

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Does it happen with all of your views or only one in particular?

Comment: @Sergio check the snapshot for my code

Comment: @Leo, yes it happen with all views.

Answer (score 0):

Some guesses:

1. Make sure there is a appsetting key like `<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />` in your `web.config` file [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405341/what-does-the-webpagesversion-setting-do). Make sure version is correct
2. Also make sure you have correctly configured `<system.web.webPages.razor>` section in `web.config` file in `views` folder, it may look like:

   `<system.web.webPages.razor>
       <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
       <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
         <namespaces>
         </namespaces>
       </pages>
   </system.web.webPages.razor>`

Hope it'l help.

Comment: I changed the version to 2, and it works but i don't know if it has any side effect on the solution.