# @ViewBag does not exist on current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I understand there are some solutions online already but I am confused by myself after trying all the solutions.

I just want to clarify the solutions which I tried:

1. Make sure `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` or `System.Web.Optimization` is there. I have `System.Web.Optimization` in References folder. I tried to install `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` in Nuget and the console told me it already exists. I think this means I have it in references already.
2. Add the namespace to `~/Views/Web.config`(not root `Web.config`). In my `~/Views/Web.config` I have:

   ```
   <system.web.webPages.razor>
      <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, 
      System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
      PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
     <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
     <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
     <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
     <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
     <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
     <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
     <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    </namespaces>
   </pages>
   </system.web.webPages.razor>
   ```

   and in my root `Web.config`:

   ```
   <system.web>
    <machineKey configSource="Config\MachineKey.config"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="20480"/>
    <globalization culture="en-CA" uiCulture="en-CA"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
     <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
       PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
       PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
     </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages buffer="true" enableViewState="false">
     <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
     </namespaces>
    </pages>
   </system.web>
   ```

   I searched online and one of the answers told me the namespaces should be the same. I did but nothing changes to me.
3. Make sure the target version. My target framework is 4.5. My MVC version is 5.2.0.0. Actually I am not understand this solution. I tried to change the framework version to 4.5.1 and the visual studio told me my version is actually 4.5. I guess my target version is OK....(Actually I do not understand this solution)
4. Add `@using System.Web.Optimization` to `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. This made something happens. My `@Scripts.Render` is OK now but `@ViewBag` still has a red line under it.
5. Delete `ComponentModelCache` and restart Visual Studio. I am using VS 2015. I tried, nothing happens.

I will perform these solutions more precisely later but I just want to know if there are other solutions I missed and worth trying. Thank you so much for the help !!

Comment: Does it appear after deploying your website or it is just the compiler saying that viewbag does not exist?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado Thank you for the reply. I just downloaded from our TFS source server and I did not deploy yet. After build, on the error list panel, it displayed these errors. But, the build will be succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few hours digging. I solved my issue. My **solution 1** can only remove the RED LINEs and it gave me 500 error When I run Localhost debug.

**Solution 1:** I simply changed the version from 3.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0 in below code of `~/Views/Web.config`:

```
  <configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

When I changed all the versions to 2.0.0.0, the red lines went away but I have 500 error. Which means `system.web.webPages.razor` loaded to the `_Layout.cshtml` correctly.

To my understanding, My below settings of `~/Views/Web.config` did not load if the `system.web.webPages.razor` version is incorrect:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

**Solution 2:** Then, I checked below part of code in root `Web.config`:

```
 <connectionStrings configSource="Config\ConnectionStrings-dev.config" />
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

the `webpages:version` is 2.0.0.0. I changed it to 3.0.0.0 to match the version in `~/Views/Web.config`, restart visual studio, it worked without any issue.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405341/what-does-the-webpagesversion-setting-do/27918972) is the one helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Take care in your project file a razor assembly is loaded, for me it was the version 2:

```
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.20715.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

In the /Views/Web.config an other version was pointed, the version 3:

```
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

And the load of the version 3 fails when the VS cshtml editor tried to load it. All razor references appear than unknown (ViewBag, @Html, etc.)
Finally when I link the same version all runs fine inside cshtml editor ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this one with MVC5 after I did something wrong: I scaffolded a razor WebPage UserControl using scaffold via templates, instead of scaffolding a default  View/Controller set for MVC5. The result did not do anything.. but the result extra 2 files in Views/ main directory did not appeal to me.. so.. next step I removed both WebPages related files, which were: Views/Web.config and Views/mycontrol.ascx

After that, I rebuilt my solution, attempt to debug in VS.. and ran into above problem. No ViewBag found on the main page .cshtml !

I solved it here by restoring the previously generated Views/Web.config, by doing the WebPages scaffold again. Then, I removed *only* the .ascx web control in /Views, left the Web.config.. saved, closed and opened VS, rebuild the program. Run. No issues.

I use Visual Studio 16.5.4, with .NET Framework 4.8 and MVC 5.2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is one thing that worked for me:  Delete the EntityFramework NuGet package.  In References, if there is still a reference to "EntityFramework.SqlServer", remove it.  Then re-download EntityFramework.  Note that this is NOT Entity Framework **CORE**.