# Razor page on Mac VS2019 ASP.net MVC is not rendering properly with _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I am stuck in this section for a while. I have checked lot of answers but none of those worked for me.

I am using VS2019 and MVC 5.2.3 framework.
I am trying to utilize the Razor views's _layout.cshtml layout page. I have created a view called 'random' but the `ViewBag` is not rendering properly. The image is below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have the MVC nuget packages correctly installed into your project, and does your web.config [reflect that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763485/11683)?

Comment: Do you see any error page when you load the `random` page? Can you share what you see on the screen?

Comment: Yes. I have the nuget packages. It is mvc 5.2.7, I updated them and I am sure it is the same in the web.config. There is no error in error pages, everthing seems fine, but the _layout just can not render.